# Differential calculus physics: how to find rate of change of distance between two particles?

Tags: calculus

At $8am$ particle $A$ is at point $(0,0)$ and moves horizontally to the right with constant velocity of $60km/h$. At the same time particle $B$ is at the  point $(0, A+B+C+5)$ and moves horizontally to the left with a velocity of $30km/h$. what are the rates of change of the distance between the two particles at $8.00am, 9.00am$? and in general time $t$?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are names of particles, but then you add them as if they are numbers.  What does that mean?  And what's $C$?

Answer (score 1):

let distance between cars be z

$z^2=x^2+y^2$

$z'=\frac{1}{z}({xx'+yy'})$

at time t the cars are moved a distance of

$30t+60t$

and

$y=A+B+C+5,y'=0,x=90t,x'=90$

$z'(t)=\frac{1}{z}(90(t)+0)$
where

$z=\sqrt{(A+B+C+5)^2+(90t)^2}$